# Undefined references to functions with C++ template methods

Tags: c++, templates

Why am I getting undefined references to the methods in this class when I call them? Will I be forced to include the implementation in the header file or is there another way to do this better?

```
class MathHelper
{
public:
    /*!
        Represents the ratio of the circumference of a circle to its diameter,
        specified by the constant, p. This value is accurate to 5 decimal places.
     */
    static const double pi = 3.14159;

    template <typename T> static const T modulo(const T &numerator, const T &denominator);
    static const double modulo(double numerator, double denominator);
    static const float modulo(float numerator, float denominator);
    template <typename T> static const T& clamp(const T &value, const T &min, const T &max);
    template <typename T> static const T wrap(const T &value, const T &min, const T &max);
    template <typename T> static bool isPowerOfTwo(T number);
    template <typename T> static T nearestPowerOfTwo(T number);
    static float aspectRatio(const QSize &size);
    template <typename T> static float aspectRatio(T width, T height);
    template <typename T> static T degreesToRadians(T degrees);
    template <typename T> static T radiansToDegrees(T radians);
    template <typename T> static T factorial(T n);

private:
    MathHelper() { }
};
```

Comment: Have you defined your functions somewhere atleast if not in the same header file?

Comment: They are in the corresponding .cpp file. I read in another post that for template methods, the compiler cannot find the definitions if they are not in the header file.

Comment: To improve the information provided in the question: What are the symbols that are undefined? Where are the templated methods defined? Are you linking all required files?

Comment: Yes, its right compiler is not able to find template definition if defined in cpp file. But what are the exact errors you are getting . Share the details of what files are linked together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the explanation and answer to your question is this [C++ faq lite answer](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12) and [the next ones](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13)

Basically, as templates are patterns to instanciate, any code unit needing it must know how to instanciate it. Therefore, the simpliest way is to define your templates in header files (like boost does). The C++ faq lite give another way to do that. In my humble opinion, I think it is cumbersome...

my2c

Comment: I guess they go in the .h then. :( Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes. Same reaction when I discovered that :)

Answer (score 0):

If we have the implementation defined in a corresponding .cpp file then we can use explicit instantiation so that compiler spits out the code that is being used by rest of the program.

Ex:- In the case of MathHelper  if it is to be instantiated with int
add the statement                       `template MathHelper<int>` in the corresponding .cpp file where the implementation is present.

There  is a disadvantage with this methodolgy from the point of view that one must explicitly instantiate every time the template class is used with a different Parameter.

But we get all the benefits of seperating implemetation from the declaration , especially when the build sizes are huge.